# WCF Operation parameter string vs .Net Type (Best Practice)

Tags: wcf

I'm developing a web services to be consumed by java and php clients.

When we write an operation that accepts Order Object, is it ok to do the below?

> void getOrderDetail (Order order)

OR

void getOrderDetail(String order)

> //Where order is a xml

Basically, what i'm after is:

1. What is the best practice to achieve above?
2. Should it problem with clients if my operation accepts Order Type?

Thank you .
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with #1. Self-describing operations are always a win- "string" doesn't give a smarter client (ie, one that can generate wire-type stubs like WCF, Axis, etc) any hints about what to do. If you use strong types on the wire, the resultant WSDL acts as a first level of documentation that can also be consumed by a client generator.